# specific issues and use cases for Magento Compilation module

Tags: php, performance, magento, compilation

I've heard various negative rumblings about Magento's compilation module causing issues.  Is it now stable enough (e.g. v1.4.2) to consider using?

Can you describe the issues that a site might encounter when using it?  I would guess that deployment of new code would be somewhat more onerous. What programming and administration practices are required to use it safely?

What quantifiable performance improvement should be expected?  Does the site need to be serving a minimum threshold of traffic to warrant it's use?

For extra credit... The benefit in using the Compilation module is (AFAIK) in flattening the directory structure to the PHP scripts to be executed.  If the site is already using APC or other opcode solutions, is the relevance of Compilation reduced?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You definitely get the boost by easing autoloading the classes.
2. The errors are coming from 3rd party extensions who write stuff to their local directory or look for licence files from their paths and the path changes if compiled to src/include.
3. If you upgrade you always need to recompile but this can be automated

Comment: Thanks @Anton, the info on the 3rd party extension providers with their "interesting" licensing code rings true, I've had bad experiences with one of the big ones in particular.  Can't wait to see a Magento Certification program...

Comment: Just wanted to add you can run the compiler from the subdir shell/ `php -f compiler.php compile` there are other options as well like enable/disable/status/etc.

Comment: Also... Magento has a good whitepaper out on optimization with some mentions of the compilation processes: http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento_PerformanceWhitepaper-EEv1-9.1.pdf

Comment: @Anton : How can we check which third party extension is looking for license and causing the issue? I am facing a similar issue.